# Madison Island links all broken

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, rwd-theme, sample-data

I just installed the sample data (1.9.0.0) and then installed Magento 1.9.0.1 after that. The homepage for Madison Island loads great (localhost/magento/index.php/) but any of the links are broken. For example, if I click "women", I get a 404 error for this page: localhost/magento/women.html. I tried searching the sample data "media" folder and I can't find that HTML page or any images.

If someone could please let me know what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate!

Thanks, Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the Use Web Server Rewrites value in Magento to No.

Comment: Thank you so much JasonS! You saved me. Sadly, I don't have any reputation points so I can't upvote you. by hellonewman

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Comment: @JasonS It didn't help me.